# How to validate a form's input value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, refresh

Sorry if this isn't the proper way to do things, I'm new to coding and stack overflow. I have this code that displays two digits; for now it just asks you at the beginning what color and what digits you want displayed. It uses a stylesheet, which I haven't included.

What I'm trying to do is have an input field instead of a prompt in the beginning. However, this doesn't seem possible to me using a single external Javascript file! As you can see, the javascript is loaded before you can input a value into the input field, and then the page just refreshes when you do enter something in.

Do I need to use seperate external Javascript files? Is this common practice? If not, how do I get the function getDigits to run after typing into the input field?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Digits</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/cs" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="light" class="lightred"></div>
<div id="seg0" class="y"></div>
<div id="segb0" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg10" class="y"></div>

<div id="seg1" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg11" class="y"></div>

<div id="seg2" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg12" class="y"></div>

<div id="seg3" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg13" class="y"></div>

<div id="seg4" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg14" class="y"></div>

<div id="seg5" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg15" class="y"></div>

<div id="seg6" class="y"></div>
<div id="seg16" class="y"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<form id="digits">
    Number: <input id="digits2" type="text" name="digitsBox" value="" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

---

```
    var y = 'y',
    n = 'n';

function changeColor(color) {
    switch(color){
        case "red":    
            y = "y";
            document.getElementById("light").className = "lightred";
            break;
        case "green":
            y = "y1";
            document.getElementById("light").className = "lightgreen";
            break;
        case "blue":
            y = "y2";
            document.getElementById("light").className = "lightblue";
            break;
    }
    //return y;
}
//changeColor(prompt("Do you want red, green, or blue?"));

var pattern = [[y, y, y, y, y, y, n], [n, y, y, n, n, n, n], [y, y, n, y, y, n, y],[y, y, y, y, n, n, y], [n, y, y, n, n, y, y], [y, n, y, y, n, y, y], [y, n, y, y, y, y, y], [y, y, y, n, n, n, n], [y, y, y, y, y, y, y], [y, y, y, n, n, y, y]];

function illuminate1(num) {

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (num === i) {
            document.getElementById("seg0").className = pattern[i][0];
            document.getElementById("seg1").className = pattern[i][1];
            document.getElementById("seg2").className = pattern[i][2];
            document.getElementById("seg3").className = pattern[i][3];
            document.getElementById("seg4").className = pattern[i][4];
            document.getElementById("seg5").className = pattern[i][5];
            document.getElementById("seg6").className = pattern[i][6];
        }
    }
}

function illuminate2(num) {


    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        if (num === i) {
            document.getElementById("seg10").className = pattern[i][0];
            document.getElementById("seg11").className = pattern[i][1];
            document.getElementById("seg12").className = pattern[i][2];
            document.getElementById("seg13").className = pattern[i][3];
            document.getElementById("seg14").className = pattern[i][4];
            document.getElementById("seg15").className = pattern[i][5];
            document.getElementById("seg16").className = pattern[i][6];
        }
    }
}

// This function extracts digits from an input text and illuminates based on the digits
function getDigits(text) {
    text = text.toString();
    text = text.split("");
    console.log(text);
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= text.length; i++) {
        text[i] = parseInt(text[i]);
        illuminate1(text[i]);
        i=i +1;
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }

    for (i=i;i <= text.length; i++) {
        text[i] = parseInt(text[i]);
        illuminate2(text[i]);
        i=i+1;
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}
//getDigits("35");
var digits = parseInt(document.getElementById('digits2').value);
getDigits(digits);
```

Comment: check `onblur` and `onkeypress` for input elements. There is no difference in how you include javascript, it will be downloaded and run in the order it is included in the page, not sure why you asked that.

Comment: try creating a http://jsfiddle.net/ as you have so much code and the problem is not clear.

Comment: @sabithpocker I'm guessing he asked that because he didn't know. It's also a perfectly reasonable question because the javascript will execute before an element it's supposed to do something with (`#digits2`) is on the page, and he has nothing to delay execution of the javascript such as a `window.onload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/CqR44/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('digits2').onkeyup=function() {
    var digits = parseInt(this.value);
    getDigits(digits);
  }
}
```

You also want to change

```
 var i=0;
 for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
```

to

```
 for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
```

---

Update

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/q5Wb9/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById('digits').onsubmit=function() {
    var digits = parseInt(this.digitsBox.value);
    getDigits(digits);
    return false; // cancel submit
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked better, thank you! Is there a method like onkeyup that works after the form has been submitted (after pushing enter)? I'd like to be able to type in both digits and then submit them to be displayed

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Can I ask a quick question? If I declare a variable such as the y or n in my javascript, will they by accessible by any other javascript I run on the page after? what about functions? Could I call my getDigits function anywhere in the HTML?

Comment: Yes. JS is available to all scripts on the page.